# Import Angular Directive Globally

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives, angular2-modules

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to define `.forRoot()` in the module for one of my Directives that we use throughout the entire app. I'd like to be able to import that module in my `app.module.ts` once, so I can set some defaults for the entire app as well.

My Directive is a wrapper for a JavaScript library, which is why there are some properties I'd like to be defined once.

Is this possible? I've been googling, but haven't seen a good example of this, though I know some nom packages are doing it.

**Directive Module**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MyDirective } from './my.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        MyDirective
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: MyModule
        }
    }
}
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MyModule.forRoot()
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [ ... ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I try the above, the Directive is not available throughout the app. I still have to import `MyModule` into the individual modules.

**Example use error**
`Can't bind to 'wbDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.`

Comment: Ideally you'll have a static `forRoot` method in your module which returns [`ModuleWithProviders<T>`](https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithProviders) with the `T` typed parameter set to your module. (A [mcve] of the current issue would help too!)

Comment: Why not have the Directive be declared by `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @ulmas That actually seems like a really simple solution. I don't have an answer to it. I'm just used to encapsulating everything in a module. I may just do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Edric Thanks. That's what I saw when googling, but wasn't able to get it to work. I added an example above. Hopefully that helps.